# Setting a custom user verification link issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, email-verification

I have been trying to send my users a custom verification email in laravel.

First I run this

```
php artisan make:notification SendRegisterEmailNotifcation
```

This has created a file called, `SendRegisterEmailNotifcation.php` inside my `App/Notifications`.

Then Inside my user controller's store method, I called that method after user insertion done.

Following is my store function,

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required','email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'confirmed','regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{12,}$/'],
            'mobile'=>['required', 'regex:/^\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{8})$/','numeric','min:9'],
            'username'=>['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'max:10', 'unique:users'],   
            'roles'=>['required'],
            'user_roles'=>['required'],
        ]);

        //Customer::create($request->all());

        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);

        $user = User::create($input);
        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

        //event(new Registered($user));
        $user->notify(new SendRegisterMailNotification());

        return redirect()->route('customers.index')
                        ->with('success','Customer created successfully. Verification email has been sent to user email.  ');
    }
```

And this is my `SendRegisterMailNotification.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SendRegisterMailNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Click Here to Activate', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Now this process works well, newly created users are receiving their emails.

But the issue is

Normally in laravel activation link has a certain format and once the user hits on the button user's account get activated and store verified date time in the user table, also the link expires in 60 minutes..

Sample verification link,

```
http://test.site/email/verify/22/3b7c357f630a62cb2bac0e18a47610c245962182?expires=1588247915&signature=7e6869deb1b6b700dcd2a49b2ec66ae32fb0b6dc99aa0405095e9844962bb53c
```

But in my case I am struggling to set that activation link and the process properly, How can I do that using the above customized email?

Comment: Can you post the code that's supposed to handle the code verification?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the link to verify email by using `verificationUrl()` function of `VerifyEmail` class from `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail` library in your `SendRegisterMailNotification` notification class.

Here it goes,

```php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;

class SendRegisterMailNotification extends VerifyEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

/**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $actionUrl  = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);  //call the verificationUrl() from base class
        $actionText  = 'Click here to verify your email';
        
        /*here, i am using view blades instead of markdown for email template*/
        return (new MailMessage)->subject('Verify your account')->view(
            'emails.user-verify',
            [
                'actionText' => $actionText,
                'actionUrl' => $actionUrl,
            ]);
    }

 /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
    
}
```

The `emails.user-verify` view looks like this

```html
        <p>
            Please click the button below to verify your email address.
        </p>

        
        <a href="{{ $actionUrl }}" class="button">{{$actionText}}</a>
        
        <p>If you did not create an account, no further action is required.</p>

        <p>
            Best regards, <br><br>
            <strong>{{config('app.signature')}}</strong><br/>
            {{ config('app.signature-title')}}
        </p>
```

Or if you prefer markdown, you can use

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url= $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);


      return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Click Here to Activate', $url)
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');

}
```